# import SimpleDirectoryReader from llama-index

Tags: python-3.x, large-language-model, llama-index

I have a conda virtual python 3.10.12 environment named LLM.  I've created it on my ubuntu 18.04 LTS server.  I've pip installed llama-index 0.6.9 into the virtual environment because llama-index wasn't available through conda.

when I try to import SimpleDirectoryReader from llama-index in a jupyter notebook using the code below, I'm getting the error below.  but "from llama_index import Document" works just fine.

Can anyone suggest how to fix the issue?

code:

```
from llama_index import SimpleDiretoryReader, Document
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 from llama_index import SimpleDiretoryReader, Document

ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleDiretoryReader' from 'llama_index' (/home/username/anaconda3/envs/LLM/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line of code

```
from llama_index import SimpleDiretoryReader, Document
```

New Line you need to add or modify

```
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, Document
```